# Any clue on what these tiny white bugs may be?

Tags: arthropod

I would like to know what the bugs in the following pictures are, they are absolutely tiny, i would say 0.5mm at most, i can't get a really sharp picture, as they seem like to hang out in the dust on furniture (which messes with the focus) and to dislike strong lighting.

If this may help i'm located in North-Eastern Italy, i first noticed them last winter, in a home where i struggled with mold on walls, and i have moved since then (along with my furniture). During all of summer in the new home i haven't noticed them around, so i thought that they may have disliked the new "habitat", but recently when the climate started to get colder and moist i've been seeing some of them again. I see them in counts of approximately 10 - 20 on a surface, so i would assume that their total population in my room would reach the thousands.

Other than in dust on my furniture i see that they like particularly boxes aswell, my assumption would be that they're some kind of acari given their almost unnoticeable size, i've also seen someone talk about dust mites. I've also found some deposit of yellowish dust in strange formations that i would assume may be eggs or feces, i'll add the picture below.

I don't believe them to be harmfull, i'm just worried that they may be eating away at my furniture or damaging my electronics with their waste. I also believe to have seen tiny strings of material similar to spider webs around, that's why i believe them to be related to acari or some tipe of spider, rather than insects, although i couldn't actually count their appendices, they look almost "hairy" in a way. Also the smaller ones look whiteish-transparent while the biggest ones are beige as far as i can see.

EDIT: i have looked up and bought a macro lens that can be attached to the phohe's camera, here's the new pictures i got, although i'll have to wait to be able to take some pictures in natural lighting as these are overexposed

[image]
[image]
[image]